# How to check a field value is must be a string when it filled out in laravel 5.4 validator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a field called middle name which is an optional field. I want to check this field if it has some value otherwise I dont want to check this field value.
How can I do this in laravel 5.4 validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**String** is an **object type** its not **primitive type** like **integer** or **char**. I didn't check how laravel handles this validation but based on documentation you have to put **nullable**. Probably because string returns an object with empty attribute. so @Gaurav Gupta's answer not going to work.

> The field under validation must be a string. If you would like to
>   allow the field to also be **null**, you should assign the **nullable** rule
>   to the field.

```
'middle_name' => 'nullable|string'
```

Comment: But why nullable is not in validation.php page.

Comment: validation.php is for translations not to get reference of validation types. for that  you should check laravel documentation

Answer (score 1):

you can just simply write

```
  'middle_name' => 'nullable|string',
```

in your validation array it check only when some value exits .Means it not required value

Comment: i already did he want to check field is string if only when he enter

Comment: It does not seems to be work, because it always throws an error.

Comment: it would be best to put it on both side because on client side it could be render by client